# Triggering google-maps event onHover from outside map

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to modify a polyline outside of the `initMap()` google-maps callback.

The JavaScript:

```
var map;
var height = window.innerHeight / 3;
var workOrders = {
    "1":[
        {
        "lat":57.77153,
        "lng":14.15588,
        "id":"7861ac93-42e9-45fb-bc2c-a4cd8319fe80"
        }
    ]
};   
var latestCoordinates = {
    "lat":57.77153,
    "lng":14.15588,
}

// Global Polyline Object
var coordinateObject = null;

$('#map').css('height', height);
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: latestCoordinates, // last added coordinates
        zoom: 13,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });
    $.each(workOrders, function (key, data) {
        coordinateObject = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: data,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#324D5E',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 8
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(coordinateObject, 'mouseover', function(e) {
            // var test = workOrders[key][0]['name ']);
            var workOrderId = workOrders[key][0]['id'];
            coordinateObject.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 0.5});
            $('#' + workOrderId + ' .list-headers, #' + workOrderId + ' .list-content').css('background', '#CCCCCC');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(coordinateObject, 'mouseout', function(e) {
            var workOrderId = workOrders[key][0]['id'];
            coordinateObject.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1});
            $('#' + workOrderId + ' .list-headers, #' + workOrderId + ' .list-content').css('background', '#FFFFFF');
        });

        coordinateObject.setMap(map);
    });
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '.list-column', function(e) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(coordinateObject, 'mouseover');
});
```

The HTML:

```
    <div id="7861ac93-42e9-45fb-bc2c-a4cd8319fe80" class="col-sm-12 list-column">
        <div class="list-headers">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="list-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm initializing the Map(), looping through the workOrder json array and adding listeners to **mouseover** and **mouseout**.

This works like a charm.
When im hovering the polyline on the map, the divs with corresponding #uuid gets a background-color.

But.. when i try to reverse the process, the problems arrive, im not able to access the **map** or the **google.maps.event** object.

### UPDATE

I've solved it by including the google.maps script at the bottom of the page.
It's working, but i still get an error when **hovering** that i'd like to get rid of.

**Solution**

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: latestCoordinates, // last added coordinates
        zoom: 13,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });
    $.each(workOrders, function (key, data) {
        coordinateObject = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: data,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#324D5E',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 8
        });

        addDomListener(google.maps.event, coordinateObject, 'mouseover', workOrders[key][0]['id'], '#CCCCCC', 0.5)
        addDomListener(google.maps.event, coordinateObject, 'mouseout', workOrders[key][0]['id'], '#FFFFFF', 1)

        coordinateObject.setMap(map);
    });
}

function addDomListener(mapEvent, coordinateObject, eventTrigger, workOrderId, onHoverBackground, opacity)
{
    mapEvent.addDomListener(coordinateObject, eventTrigger, function(e) {
        coordinateObject.setOptions({strokeOpacity: opacity});
        $('#' + workOrderId + ' .list-headers, #' + workOrderId + ' .list-content').css('background', onHoverBackground);
    });

    $('#'+workOrderId+'.list-column').each(function() {
        var col = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
        mapEvent.addDomListener(col, eventTrigger, function(event) {
            mapEvent.trigger(coordinateObject, eventTrigger, {

            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined commonjs.3

- > _.qi  @  common.js:3
- > (anonymous function)   @   poly.js:22
- > _.H.trigger    @   js?key=XXXXXX&callback=initMap:88
- > (anonymous function)   @   a7184edc-46e9-4080-b4f3-3e6676d08d07:155*

Comment: Your problem is probably because `coordinateObject` is a local variable to your `initMap` function. So if you're trying to access it outside that function, it won't be accessible (and you'll just be getting a `null`).  Make it a global variable.

Comment: "setting the coordinateObject global and trying to trigger like this:"

Comment: What does the code the browser sees look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including data for `$workOrderPositions;`,  `$latestCreatedCoordinates;`, etc.